# Create symbolic link with sub-directories

Tags: linux, symlink

I'm creating a symbolic link using:

```
    ln -s /usr/local/nfs/etc /usr/local/gemini/application
```

etc is created but the sub-folders that are in application are not visible in etc.

Is it possible to create a symbolic link and get access to all the sub-folders in the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both `/usr/local/nfs/etc` and `/usr/local/gemini/application` exist as directories, your command

```
ln -s /usr/local/nfs/etc /usr/local/gemini/application
```

creates a symbolic link `etc` in `/usr/local/gemini/application` referencing `/usr/local/nfs/etc`.

If you want to see `application` and its content in `/usr/local/nfs/etc` you have to swap the command line arguments:

```
ln -s /usr/local/gemini/application /usr/local/nfs/etc
```

This will create a symbolic link `application` in `/usr/local/nfs/etc`.

See [man ln](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html)